# django tables2 create extra column with hyperlink

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using django-table2 and wanted to get an extra column Edit for each row. Here I am getting only a dash(-) instead of any link. Could you please help.

```
tables.py
class computertable(tables.Table):
    Edit = tables.LinkColumn("computer_edit", args=[A("int:id")])
    class Meta:
        model = Computer
        fields = ['computer_name','Edit']

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.computer_list, name='djform-home'),
    path('computer_edit/<int:id>/', views.computer_edit, name='computer_edit'),]
```

Comment: Can you add `text` for `LinkColumn`? I did not use django-table2 in any of my projects but I saw this argument on documentation: https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#django_tables2.columns.LinkColumn I guess the default value is "-" sign

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Deniz. Its works.

```
Edit = tables.LinkColumn("computer_edit", text = "Edit",args=[A("pk")])
```